# OData Web Api with Caching

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I have a problem and hope someone can help :)

I'm using OData Web Api (Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData) and I'd like to do some request caching. I have the following considerations:

- I know my data only updates every 15 min, which is when I'd invalidate my cache
- I've tried Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching which works for me as long as there's no Authentication Header. But half of my request contain Authentication headers containing a signed JWT of a authenticated user from a trusted service (all internal services/users)
- I'm trying to use a Resource Filter but the problem I'm having here is the OData Controllers return Queryables, not only do I think it doesn't make sense to cache them but the get disposed at end of the request.

Here is my OData controller, pretty simple:

```
    [ODataRoute()]
    public IQueryable<T> Get(ODataQueryOptions opts)
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
    }
```

And here is my attempted ResourceCaching filter:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

namespace Service.Helpers
{
    public class ResourceCacheFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        private IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

        public ResourceCacheFilter(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
        {
            _memoryCache = memoryCache;
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path + context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
            if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue(path, out ObjectResult value))
            {
                context.Result = value;
            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            if (context.Exception != null) return;

            var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path + context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
            var cacheEntryOpts = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
            _memoryCache.Set(path, context.Result, cacheEntryOpts);
        }
    }
}
```

Yes I realize the path is probably not the best key, I'll take suggestions :)

Any help on how I could make progress on my problem would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could use EF Core Interceptors to cache data in the EF level? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors